# How to find string that contains commands in batch

Tags: batch-file

stackoverflow.

I've been working on a major project in batch recently for a friend of mine. 
I know that there are better ways to do this, but i just wanted to challenge batch coding :)

So, here's my issue:

I want to be able to find a string called:

```
if "%MORELISTINPUT%"=="%COUNTER2%" goto blablatest2
```

now here comes the challenge, i've used this code so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (moreserver.bat) DO (
    ECHO %%A
    IF "%%A" EQU "if "%MORELISTINPUT%"=="%COUNTER2%" goto blablatest2" (
      echo if "%%MORELISTINPUT%%"=="%%COUNTER2%%" goto %NEWNAME%
    )
  )
) >moreserverout.txt
pause
```

But it just wont find the text. (I'm thinking it's due to commands and variables, but i'm not sure)

I've tried adding %'s around the variables, added ^'s before commands and also variables and it just wont work.

How would i go about using the string containing both commands and variables as plain text?

Thanks in advance!

~Niklas

edit: Here's links to my "project files"

Doesn't work for me tho, sorry ^^
I'm calling this small program from within a bigger program, and when i'm running this it just displays a line saying

%%MORELISTINPUT%%"=="%%COUNTER2%%" goto %NEWNAME%

between every line. (it lists all lines in the moreserver.bat file in the cmd window)

Here's a link to the complete files:

http://pastebin.com/u/MinervaXcel

The top 4 ones named "WoW Client Config" are the ones that are used.

"Main" is as said the main one. "Chooseserver.bat" is the one that's containing the code in question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
IF "%%A" EQU "if "%%MORELISTINPUT%%"=="%%COUNTER2%%" goto blablatest2" (
```

as you did on the following line (worked for me)

Comment: Doesn't work for me tho, sorry ^^
I'm calling this small program from within a bigger program, and when i'm running this it just displays a line saying 

%%MORELISTINPUT%%"=="%%COUNTER2%%" goto %NEWNAME%

between every line. (it lists all lines in the moreserver.bat file in the cmd window)

Comment: @NiklasJørgensen - Not sure what you are doing wrong, but Magoo's suggestion works for me.